# string array.Contains?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, .net-2.0

.NET 2

```
string[] myStrings = GetMyStrings();    
string test = "testValue";
```

How can I verify if `myStrings` contains `test`?

Comment: vb.net and c# are not the same language...

Comment: @Chris Thompson: this is eddy556 ....

Comment: I.Q test ? such a question from a ~4K guy ?! (Using .NET 2.0 is not clear)

Comment: @Xaqron: I'm a 27K guy and I didn't know the answer. The point is, I know how to do it in .NET 3.5 but that doesn't help me for my legacy 2.0 project.

Comment: Just check [Array.IndexOf(myStrings, test) >= 0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 19):

In .NET 2.0, you could do the following if you want the index:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(
    myStrings,
    delegate(string s) { return s.Equals(test); }
);
```

`index` will be `-1` if `myStrings` does not contain `test`.

If you merely want to check for existence:

```
bool exists = Array.Exists(
    myStrings,
    delegate(string s) { return s.Equals(test); }
);
```

Answer (score 11):

I have found an elegant answer at the page here http://www.dotnettoad.com/index.php?/archives/10-Array.Contains.html. What you have to do in .NET 2.0 is to cast to IList and call Contains method.

```
(IList<string> mystrings).Contains(test);
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a .NET 2.0 compliant approach. Using `Array.Find` will return null if the value isn't found.

**C# Approach**

```
string[] myStrings = { "A", "B", "testValue" };
string test = "testValue";
string result = Array.Find(myStrings, delegate(string s) { return s == test; });
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
```

If you need a case insensitive match use `s.Equals(test, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.

**EDIT:** with VB.NET 2.0 more effort is required since it doesn't support anonymous delegates. Instead you would need to add a `Function` and use `AddressOf` to point to it. You would need to set the `testValue` as a member or property since it will not be passed in to the predicate method. In the following example I use `Array.Exists`.

**VB.NET Approach**

```
' field or property ' 
Dim test As String = "testValue"

Sub Main
    Dim myStrings As String() = { "A", "B", "testValue" }       
    Dim result As Boolean = Array.Exists(myStrings, AddressOf ContainsValue)
    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub

' Predicate method '
Private Function ContainsValue(s As String) As Boolean
    Return s = test
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for VB solution, even if I need C# one, maybe for VB people will be useful...

Comment: I missed the 2.0 and VB requirement.  This will work, of course, but a call to Array.IndexOf might be simpler.

Comment: @Chris agreed. This is closer to a `Contains` type of check but requires more effort than `IndexOf`.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using a static array, you could use a List:

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>(GetMyStrings());
if(myStrings.Contains("testValue"))
{
    // Do Work
}
```

Comment: I use `string[] letters = "a, b, c, d".Split();`. Is it optimal for such a elementary function to use conversions from Array to List?

Comment: @serhio - Code first, optimize later if needed. Unless you're constructing these lists on a large scale there really shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 8):

Thought I would add another to the mix, first available in .NET 3.5, I believe:

```
Enumerable.Contains(myStrings.ToArray(), test)
```

Comment: What this means is that by `using System.Linq`, you can write `myStrings.Contains(test)`, as `Enumerable.Contains` is an extension method. (BTW, .NET version 3.5 uses the same CLR as .NET version 2.0, so this usually works in ".NET 2.0".)

Answer (score 2):

```
bool ContainsString(string[] arr, string testval)
{
    if ( arr == null )
        return false;
    for ( int i = arr.Length-1; i >= 0; i-- )
        if ( arr[i] == testval )
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

And this will have the best performance ever. :P

Comment: @serhio. I did. Thrice. You ask to determine whether or not a particular string is contained in the string array. This is how you do it. If this isn't what you need, please fix your question.

Comment: Just change the array from test to myStrings and this answer will work.  How does it not work for you?

Comment: Oh, wait, .NET 2.0. Well, same thing, just change the delegate syntax. OK, if you REALLY want it, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Vilx - because the OP original had a VB.Net tag on the question.  Now I see that it has been removed.  I now see his original code is also C#.  I missed that and was going by the tag.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway - Actually he didn't. Check the edit history. Some other guy for reasons unknown added the VB.NET tag. OP removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is almost the exact same question on msdn.
[Find String in String Array](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d69f389e-4427-4806-bbd1-82b8eff8e000/)
As others have said you really have two options:
1) Use a list for easier checking
2) Loop through your array to find the string

Answer (score 1):

you can use Array.BinarySearch as described below.

```
 string[] strArray = GetStringArray();
        string strToSearch ="test";
        Array.BinarySearch(strArray, strToSearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Sub Main
    Dim myStrings(4) As String
    myStrings(0) = "String 1"
    myStrings(1) = "String 2"
    myStrings(2) = "testValue"
    myStrings(3) = "String 3"
    myStrings(4) = "String 4"

    Dim test As String = "testValue"

    Dim isFound As Boolean = Array.IndexOf(myStrings, test) >= 0

    If isFound Then
        Console.WriteLine("Found it!")
    End If
End Sub
```

This should work for .Net 2.0 and VB.Net.

Comment: The OP's issue is that it's not .NET 2.0 compatible with the lambdas.

Comment: If the OP is using VS2008 then they can use lambdas when targeting .NET 2.0.

Answer (score -3):

I assume you want to check if any elements in your array contains a certain value (test).  If so you want to construct a simple loop.  In fact I think you should [click here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=loop+through+array+c%23).