# Python 'in' operator equivalent in C# (.NET 2.0)

Tags: c#, python, extension-methods, operator-keyword

I love **pythons** `in-operator` and I would like to write it and use it in a **c#** project. ***I only have access to .NET Framework 2.0***. I am using the code below but I don't understand the compile error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public static bool In<T>(this T item, IEnumerable<T> sequence) {
    if (sequence == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");

    return sequence.Contains(item);
}
```

I also have a reference to `System` as well, but I get the following compile error:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and no extension method 'Contains' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I don't understand what reference I might be missing!

***EDIT:***

Seems like there is no Linq in .NET framework 2.0. So I downloaded and used the following package: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx it includes a `namespace System.Linq` which solves the compile error.

I want to test it with the following code:

```
char[] x = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
if('a'.In(x))
{
    ;   
}
```

But I get confusing errors:

```
'char' does not contain a definition for 'In' and no extension method 'In' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

***EDIT:***
A clean built solved the issues.

Comment: Linq is not available in .NET Framework 2.0,so you wont be able to use "Contains"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Contains` static method is defined inside [System.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX).

If you add the line `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file, your code should compile.

Incidentally, isn't the Contains method identical to Python's 'in' operator? You don't really gain much from creating a custom method, except that you get to type a few less characters/get to reverse the operands.

If you're using .NET 2.0, you might be able to adapt one of the methods in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3917589/646543) in lieu of using Linq.

Comment: Can we use "include" instead of "using" in c#?

Comment: @Rain -- whoops! You're right, it should be "using". I got mixed up with a different language.

Comment: @Michael0x2a, sorry, see updated question I missed to mention the huge elephant in the room.

Comment: System.Linq is not in .Net v2.0, I think. It starts from v3.5.

Comment: @NonStatic - yeah, the question originally didn't mention that. I'm looking for an alternate method right now.

Comment: @Michael0x2a. I think I found something which I am gonna try. http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx not sure if it works.

Comment: @theAlse - I also found a variety of different methods you can try here that replicate 'contains' in .NET 2.0: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3917589/646543